# My variable dosen't affect arraylist

Tags: python, brute-force

i'm trying to make a bruteforce-ing program and my first step was to make it so i can cycle through characters whit numbers. But when i change the variable it does not affect the character being printed.

```
chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", 
"n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

n1 = 0
#for future expancion
n2 = 0
n3 = 0
n4 = 0

char1 = chars[n1]
#for future expansion
char2 = chars[n2]
char3 = chars[n3]
char4 = chars[n4]

while(n1 < 26):
    print(n1)
    n1 += 1
    print(char1)
```

The output is just 0, a, 1, a, 2, a ect. But i want it to make the characters rise as well.

Comment: `print(chars[n1])`

Comment: This isn't an Excel sheet where a cell (or variable) changes its value just because you changed a different cell (variable). That's not how imperative programming works. If you want the value of `char1` to change, you have to change it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey now I understand why such mistakes are made. Because of _evil excel macro programming_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating `n1` will not automatically update `char1`. That variable is not a pointer to a certain position in the array (and even if it were, changing the pointer-offset afterwards would not affect the pointer itself), but it takes the value that index in the array had *at the moment of assignment*.

You will have to re-assign the value

```
n1 += 1
char1 = chars[n1]
print(char1)
```

or, probably clearer, access the array directly:

```
n1 += 1
print(chars[n1])
```